# How to change an item's position trough style.position?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to move my text label in the custom position using `document.style.position` I have this script:

```
var clickHandler = function() {
    var doc = document.getElementById("result");
    doc.style.visibility = "visible";
    doc.style.color = "#ff0000";
    doc.style.position = "left:150px";
}
```

(seen [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute) as position tutorial). Where's I'd mistaken?

Comment: It should be `doc.style.left= "150px"` `position` is `absolute/relative` etc

Comment: CSS Position: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is:

```
doc.style.position = "absolute";  // or "relative" or "fixed" or etc
doc.style.left = "150px";
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 4):

Check this code:

```
var clickHandler = function() {
    var doc = document.getElementById("result");
    doc.style.visibility = "visible";
    doc.style.color = "#ff0000";
    doc.style.left= "150px";
}
```